# Receive output of debug function from child process in parent

Tags: node.js, debugging

so, what am I trying to achieve:

I am running master process, which forks 2 other node processes. I am using [this debug library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) from npm and I need it's output (of the debug function function) of child processes to be piped to parent's outputs (`stdout`, `stderr`).

Currently what I'm getting successfully piped is `console.log("...");` but not:

```
var log = require('debug')('service');
log.color = 3;
log("...");
```

I am forking child processes using this code:

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;

var child_options = {
    cwd: __dirname,
    env: process.env,
    stdio: [ 'ignore', process.stdout, process.stderr, 'ipc' ],
    deatached: false,
    shell: true
};

var job_node = fork('job_node', [], child_options);
```

Could anyone help me find out what the problem might be? Thank you :)

**EDIT**:
This problem is probably not caused by some kind of error in stream piping -
 instead there is something with existing/non-existing console window, attached terminal.

When I tried to run the server from within PhpStorm, using built-in tools, it showed ONLY the `console.log` function outputs *even from master process*.

TheKronnY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**:

Just for the sake of trying, I tried to use `debug.enable` function in the master process and *it worked*.

I used `debug.enable('master,job,service');` to enable used namespaces in other processes and it worked, so I do not know why, but other namespaces, created in the child processes were disabled by default.